# Splitting arrays in foreach

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I'm using Exchange message tracking to split recipients from an array so they appear on their own line.

When I run the following:

```
foreach ($recepient in $recepients){
    $recepient.Recipients
}
```

The recipients are shown as a list.

However, when I add the variable as an expression, the output show's the recipients still in the array.

Also tried using:

```
Split-Array -inArray $user -Size 1
```

without much progress.

The output is not splitting the recipient array. Example:

```
Timestamp           recipients       Messagesubject      eventID
---------           ----------       ----------------    -------
01/01/2019 10:11:00 {User1,User2}    Subject             Deliver
```

```
$Report = @()

$Sender = "sender@email.com"
$recepients = Get-MessageTrackingLog -EventId "Deliver" -Sender $Sender -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-8) -MessageSubject "Subject"

foreach ($recepient in $recepients) {
    $user = $recepient.Recipients

    $Data = $recepient | select timestamp,@{L=”recepients”;E={$user}},eventid

    $report += $Data
}
$Report
```

The goal is to have each user on their own line

```
Timestamp           recipients     Messagesubject      eventID
---------           ----------     ----------------    -------
01/01/2019 10:11:00 User1          Subject             Deliver
01/01/2019 10:11:00 User2          Subject             Deliver
```

Comment: You will need a nested foreach loop to extract the user in the recipients property.

Comment: [1] this `$recepients = get-messagetrackinglog` is NOT getting _recipients_ ... it is getting messages. [*grin*] [2] that means that this `foreach ($recepient in $recepients)` is NOT giving your _recipients_ ... it is giving you _messages_. [3] that means that this `$user =  $recepient.Recipients` is finally giving you one-or-more actual recipients. ///// if you want those recipients listed on individual lines, you will need to iterate thru that list. if all you want is to expand the list, use `$Message.Recipients -join ';'` to give you a semicolon delimited text string.

Answer (score 2):

If you have nested arrays in a result and you want to extract them you can use a nested loop and a custom object like this:

```
foreach ($recepient in $recepients){
    Foreach ($SingleRecipient in $recepient.Recipients) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User = $SingleRecipient
            timestamp = $recepient.timestamp
            MessageSubject = $recepient.MessageSubject
            eventid = $recepient.eventid
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant thank you. Expended using pscustomobject as well as adding this to a variable.

Using *nested* foreach loop made more sense.